# Display running GUI on another login

Tags: gui

I login to an ubuntu 14 system from multiple computer using remote desktop. After starting a GUI process, I have to go to another computer.  I can login again with same username/password and I can find the process ID. Is there a way to show the GUI?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you reword it so as to make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Let me make my question more clear by giving an example. I use my ubuntu system to started an  image processing program. I can login to the same system with same username using remote desktop. I know the image processing program is still running by using ps -ef command. I want to see the GUI of the running program. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You want to login from several remote computers into the same PC session, right?

I have a setup like that when I have a computer I work on and sometimes I need to go to different rooms and need to look up something locally. Then I just use VNC (thats one of the protocols for Remote desktop) to connect to the computer. You need to run a VNC server on that computer. You would need to enable "multiple" or "shared" sessions. Since i am logged in locally the session is never closed when I remotely log off. I can even be logged in from different remote rooms to the computer. Works fine. 
As usual with Linux there are several programs to choose from e.g."vnc4server" or "tightvncserver", "x11vnc". I did use X11vnc and can not say a lot about the others. I guess there are pretty comparable. X11vnc has a bit old-fashioned look and feel. I would recommend to check out the Ubuntu's wiki pages for those programs and decide by the best installation tutorial.

In case for some reason you can not have a session running on the target computer. There is a more advanced way to set up a re-entrant session capability for remote logins. That could be used for a remote headless PC that does not have a local user. When you would remote login there, a new session would be started. When you log off it would be closed again.

CatMan

By the way, if you are on the web, be sure to set up VNC over SSH.

Comment: I connect to my ubuntu box using microsoft remote desktop and xfce4. I found this is faster than vnc. Thanks for replying!